# I'm starting! Need help. moderncvstyle with an Overleaf template. Trouble!

Tags: errors, compiling, moderncv

So I'm trying to create a CV using the Overleaf platform... I'm just starting with this whole LaTeX... I didn't even know such thing existed. Learning the basics...

The template is awesome and I've made some progress! Major KUDOS to Mahesh Gaikwad!!! But, I'm having a hard time with some "compile errors" I can't seem to solve... I guess these are due to "portuguese accents and special characters".

I did insert this:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

I'm not sure it solved the problem as I have been using the LaTeX codes for the letters.

I can't seem to get past the first detected error so... Is there a way to bypass an error and check the remaining code? Major Trouble! I really have to submit this CV ASAP! I'm getting desperate for help to get through with it and meet the deadline.

Below is one I can't seem to solve. Maybe there is a lot more... Give me a "helping hand". It will be very very appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...es Licenciatura em Ci\^encias Biof\�
                                                  ��{\i }sicas}\ifthenelse {...
l.34 \cventry{2009}
                   {Frequ\^ncia da Licenciatura em Artes Visuais - Multim\'d...
```

Comment: Daniel, please paste a minimal working example (MWE) of the code you're using. Simply adding those three lines of code to the CV (supposing it's the right one) generates no errors. I don't know what `\ifthenelse` is doing in a title... maybe that's the problem. And please stop using codes for accents. It's tiresome, useless, and old-fashioned ("cafona") in Portuguese -- remember you could be typing a thesis with thousands of those!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please take a moment to take our [Tour](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour)!  You may also want to look at what makes a good Minimal Working Example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` you can use utf-8 encoding to write your text.  That means you can directly type `EDUCAÇÃO E FORMAÇÃO` to get the correct letters into your cv. That means you need **not** to use code like `\^n` or `\'d` for portuguese accents and special characters (no ascii characters) ...

With the following MWE (saved for example as file `mwe.tex` with utf8-encoding!)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    % <======================================
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel} % <======================================
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       % <======================================

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{Carlos}{Rodrigues}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{EDUCAÇÃO E FORMAÇÃO} % <=======================================
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{09/1977--07/1979}{Degree}{Escola de Formação Profissional de Bragança}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\end{document}
```

you get the following result without error messages and two warnings (okay, call of `moderncv` files):

[image: resulting pdf]